# Property map does not exist when trying to iterate over props data

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-props

I am trying to iterate over a JSON data set which i am sending as a prop. I tried printing the props and i see that the data is there. However i cannot seem to use .map as it states that it is not a property of the prop data.

Parent Component:

```
function HomePage() {

return (
   <React.StrictMode>
     <VolvoCarsProducstListPage cd={cars} />
   </React.StrictMode>
 );
}

export default HomePage;
```

Child component:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

export interface CarDataProps {
cars: Car[];
};

export interface Car {
 id: string,
 modelName: string,
 bodyType: string,
 modelType: string,
 imageUrl: string
}

export const VolvoCarsProducstListPage = (props: CarDataProps) => {

    const carsJSONData = props;
    carsJSONData.map()
    console.log(carsJSONData);

return (
    <div className="volvo-product-list-page">
    </div>

);
```

};

Comment: props is an object - try `props.cd` and you will have more luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Property map does not exist because `carsJSONData` is not an array it's the `props` the component recieves and this latter is of type `CarDataProps` which is an object that contains an array so you cannot map through it.
however you can map through `carsJSONData.cars` or simply make `carsJSONData = props.cars` instead, if you want `carsJSONData` to be the property `cars` of the received props which is an array and pass props to the component this way :

```js
<VolvoCarsProducstListPage cars={cars} />
```

to avoid any conflict

Comment: Not working when using carJSONData = props.cars the console log gives me a undefined then. But it allows me to map at least

Comment: sorry my bad  didn't see that you pass the cars array as cd to the component so make it  recives the property cars instead as shown in the updated answer to avoid any conflicts

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to call `.map` on an object containing cars, not the array with cars. if you change these two lines it should work

```js
    const carsJSONData = props;
    carsJSONData.map()
```

to

```js
    const carsJSONData = props.cars;
    carsJSONData.map(x => x)
```

Comment: Not working, i get undefined when i log carsJSONData when doing that. But it allows me to use map